# Set background-image to a div

Tags: html

I have tried to code my page as follows:

```
<div class="Conttent-Group">
    <div class="Conttent-Group-Body">
        <div class="Conttent-Body-Right">
            <div class="Conttent-Body-Left">
                 <h1><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">News operations</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and although the following css:

```
* {
    background-color: #006;
}
.Conttent-Group {
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 788px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}
.Conttent-Group-Body {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 386px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    background: url (Image / module-bg-bodynew.jpg) repeat-x top center;
}
.Conttent-Body-Right {
    height: 30px;
    background: url (image / module-bg-rightnew.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}
.Conttent-Body-Left {
    background: url (image / module-bg-leftnew.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
}
.Conttent-Body-Left div {
    background: #fff;
    border:> 1px solid # C6B389;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 7 pixels;
    height: 243px;
}
.Conttent-Body-Left h1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0 7 pixels;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: # E1F1FE;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

But when running my code I only see the background-color

```
* { background-color: # 006; }
```

And not the background-images I have set. How can I fix this and show the images?

Comment: Please edit the code inside your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using **`* {background-color: #006}`**. The `* selector` targets **every** element, thats on your side, thats why every background color is the same.

When you are using an image as background, first of all look up its file path:

```
/index.html
/style.css
/images/
/images/picture1.jpg
/images/picture2.jpg
```

If you want to target an picture, you always have to choose the file path regarding to your **css file**. So in this case for example your path is `images/picture1.jpg`. Although be aware of uppercase and lowercase letters inside your file structure (like `Images` or `images`) or not wanted spaces.

Using this you can set your background-image, and although add multiple variables, like:

```
background-image: url(images/picture1.jpg); /* no spaces inside your url */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or "repeat-x", "repeat-y" */
background-size: cover; /* for a fullscreen background */
background-color: #fff /* for everything your background images does not cover */

/* or combine them all into one */
background: url(images/picture1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
```

---

Furthermore you have got quite a lot of errors inside your code. Maybe you should consider refreshing the basics, using online helpers like [**codeacademy**](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web) or something else you will find.